# reading data from the json file in Python for automating the web application

Tags: python, json, selenium, xpath

I have a code for automating web application( i am using Python and Selenium ),where i am entering the static data, i want to use JSON file to send the data to the application, can anyone please help me to how to write the code to pick from JSON file. Here is my code :-

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("some xpath").send_keys("xxxx")
pass = driver.find_element_by_xpath("some xpath").send_keys("xxxx")
phone_no = driver.find_element_by_xpath("some xpath").send_keys("xxxx")
```

Please help me in how to read data from json file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but, the simplest to read json is using the json module. json.load deserializes the json into a python object, usually a dictionary.

```
import json

with open('file-name.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

# access json (now python object) like this... data['some-field']
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, i will try to use this in my code

Comment: A shorter code would be `data = json.load(open(data_file))` in one line, and would achieve the same goal of reading a file into a variable as json data.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `send_keys` function, you can't just send the json as is, because it will add '\n' after every json attribute. Here are three ways to do it:

Way 1 - Do not use as a json, just use plain text

```py
path = os.path.abspath("../excel_upload.json")
with open(path, "r") as fp:
    obj = fp.readlines()
    print(str(obj))
                driver.find_element_by_name("name").send_keys((obj))
```

Way 2 - Serialization of the json, which is in the form of Dict, using `json.dumps`.

Way 3 - Loading the json and then removing '\n' by taking it in a string.

I used the first way for taking the complete json text, while second way to use key pairs. There will be a better way, please update with better solutions.

Loading and reading json is fine, but using it in `send_keys` is a different issue.